# How can I add html to a phoenixframework flash message?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

What I have tried the following in my controller:

```
conn
|> put_flash(:info, "text with <a href=\"link\">twitter<\\a>"
|> render "index.html"
```

I am displaying the messages like this (app.html.slim with bootstrap 4):

```
.alert.alert-success role="alert"= get_flash(@conn, :success)
.alert.alert-info role="alert"= get_flash(@conn, :info)
.alert.alert-warning role="alert"= get_flash(@conn, :warning)
.alert.alert-danger role="alert"= get_flash(@conn, :error)
```

Maybe there is an option? (although the [documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.ConnTest.html#put_flash/3) suggests otherwise)

EDIT: The resulting html is:

```
<div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">text with &lt;a href="link"&gt;twitter&lt;\a&gt;</div>
```

Comment: Are you getting an error with this code? or wrong output? or something else?

Comment: No error, just the same string I put in. No link escaped.

Comment: You mean the HTML is escaped and you literally see `<a href=..` on the page? Can you post the generated HTML? That will make things clearer.

Comment: You can use `= raw(get_flash(...))` to insert unescaped content but the answer posted by Pawel below is better for this particular use case.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is what I've done in my project:

```
defmodule MyApp.PageController do
  use MyApp.Web, :controller
  import Phoenix.HTML.Link

  def index(conn, _params) do
    conn
    |> put_flash(:info, ["Please, visit ", link("Twitter", to: "http://twitter.com"), "!"])
    |> render("index.html")
  end
end
```

Notice, the flash message content is not a plain string, but rater [IO list](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/elixir-and-io-lists-part-1-building-output-efficiently/), when one of the elements is result of [`Phoenix.HTML.Link.link/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_html/Phoenix.HTML.Link.html#link/2).

Hope that helps!